# How to ignore timezones in Sails.js

Tags: date, datetime, timezone, sails.js, waterline

I have a legacy database where dates are stored **without timezone information**. I need to read these into the client at face value, that is, `2 pm` in the server timezone should be interpreted as `2 pm` in the client timezone.

I was able to remove timezones when querying the server by replacing `Date.prototype.toJSON` with a method that simply ignores timezones. Now I need a similar solution server-side.

This is not a duplicate of [how to set local timezone in sails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24104725/how-to-set-local-timezone-in-sails-js-or-express-js). I want to **unset** it.

**EDIT**

The dates are correct in `PostGRES`, but Waterline/Sails seem to translate it to UTC before turning it into JSON. I don't want this to happen. A query in PostGRES returns `2013-02-28 15:00:00`, but when I console.log the result from the same query in Sails (through a [custom made toJSON method](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/records/to-json)) I get `"2013-02-28T07:00:00.000Z"` instead. And then it gets sent to the client and translated to the client's local time... you get the picture.

Comment: Can you add more info and code: where do you see the timezone changes: in the db? controller? what db are you using exactly? how do you send the date as string or epoch time? how do you parse it back to date? what did you do to "remove" the timezone on the client side?

Comment: You can always use strings and numbers.  The `Date` object is just one approach.

Comment: @MattJohnson Yes. The question is just how to, say, replace .toJSON for a Waterline.js column only.

Comment: @OferHerman, please see edit. It parses back to date through socket.io. I'm not sure about the internals. This is all "out of the box" Sails.js functionality.

Answer (score 1):

So [sails-postgresql timezone support is broken](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-postgresql/issues/153). This is my workaround. I parse the date string back to a JavaScript Date instance, set it to UTC time, then return the ISO string with the timezone chopped off. The client never complains. :)

This is all done in `api/model/theModel.js`, as explained in the [docs](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/records/to-json).

```
    toJSON: function() {

        var obj = this.toObject();

        if (obj.datetime) {

            var date = new Date(Date.parse(obj.datetime)),
                y = date.getFullYear(), 
                m = date.getMonth(), 
                d = date.getDate(), 
                h = date.getHours(), 
                M = date.getMinutes(),
                newDate = new Date();

            newDate.setUTCFullYear(y); 
            newDate.setUTCMonth(m); 
            newDate.setUTCDate(d); 
            newDate.setUTCHours(h);
            newDate.setUTCMinutes(M);

            obj.datetime = newDate.toISOString().slice(0,-8);
        }

        return obj;
    },
```